Should we merge 'lost' and 'recovery'?
lost and recovery generally cover the same ground. I think that lost should be a synonym of recovery.

Given that I didn't get a response, I'm going to interpret that as a 'no'.

I'd rather "be bold" like in Wikipedia and interpret it as a "yes".

@Lohoris The problem is that I can't do it myself, because I don't have 5 upvotes in those tags. A few other users can though: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/81/lemonginger http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/44/emansipater http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/78/ripper234

recovery has been proposed as a synonym for lost. You can vote here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/tags/lost/synonyms
